# How do I get R to recognise a date-time column in my dataframe, DF? MY attempt at the solution is below

Tags: r, date, datetime, dataframe, datetime-format

I first installed and loaded the lubridate package
I then created a dataframe, DF.

```
date <- c("2018-06-25", "2018-06-25", "2018-06-26", "2018-06-26", "2018-06-27", "2018-06-27")

time <- c("10:11:11","10:30:30","11:00:00","11:05:30", "12:06:01","12:15:30")

DF <- Data.frame(date, time)
```

Next I created a date_time column in DF.

```
DF$Date_Time <- paste(DF$date, DF$time)
```

Then I used the following function in my attempt to get R to recognise DF$Date_Time as a date-time column;

```
DF$Date_Time <- as.Date(ymd_hms(DF$Date_Time))
```

However R just got rid of the times in that column and kept the dates. So I was left with a column of dates in DF$Date_Time. Can someone let me know where i went wrong or direct me to a better solution please?

Comment: you don't need  `as.Date(ymd_hms(DF$Date_Time))`. just `ymd_hms(DF$Date_Time)`

Comment: You also have a typo in your code `Data.frame(date, time)` should be `data.frame(date, time)`

Comment: @phiver Okay thanks! It works now!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting the Date_Time column without using as.Date()

```
DF$Date_Time <- dmy_hms(DF$Date_Time)
```